# How to handle exception/error thrown from function in test?

Tags: unit-testing, error-handling, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

I am writing test for one function. Here are the files -

```
// A.ts
export abstract class A{
    protected abstract method();
}

//B.ts
export class B extends A{
    constructor(){  super();  }

protected async method(){
    init(request);
    //some more method calls
}

private async init(request){
    try {
        const reqUrl = new URL('http://localhost' + request.url);
        let param = reqUrl.searchParams.get("value") || "";
        if (!param) {
            throw "Value missing in request";
        }
        someFunc();
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        throw e;
    }
}
}

//B.spec.ts
describe("tests", ()=> {
    afterEach(() =>{
        jest.resetAllMocks();
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    })
    it("test on request", async()=>{
        let bVal = new B();
        let socket = new Socket();
        let request = new IncomingMessage(socket);
        await B["init"](request);
        socket.destroy();
        const spied = jest.spyOn(util,'someFunc').mockImplementation(()=>{});
        expect(spied).toBeCalledTimes(0);
    })
})
```

The test simply send the request without the query parameter 'value' so the function init() will throw error. When I am enclosing the function call B"init" inside test in try catch block then the test is passing but without the try catch block it is failing.
I do not want to use the try catch block in my test so how can I handle the thrown exception?

Answer (score 0):

If you are throwing:

```js
throw "Value missing in request";
```

then you test it like this:

```js
it("test on request", async()=>{
  let bVal = new B();
  await expect(bVal["init"]({})).rejects.toEqual("Value missing in request");
})
```

If you throw like this:

```js
throw new Error("Value missing in request");
```

then you test it like this:

```js
it("test on request error", async()=>{
  let bVal = new B();
  await expect(bVal["init"]({})).rejects.toThrow("Value missing in request");
})
```

Comment: init() is a private method and hence cant be called directly.